# Encryption options for text file

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I would like to know how i would encrypt and decrypt a small text file in python? It will not have a ton of data. With few data for example.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use a module like [simple-crypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt) to encrypt and decrypt the string that you read/write to the file. The usage is very simple and can be easily integrated into your program:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt
ciphertext = encrypt('password', plaintext)
plaintext = decrypt('password', ciphertext)
```

There are also [examples](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt/blob/master/src/simplecrypt/example-interactive.py) on Github that you can view.

Comment: This is a good solution, it uses AES and an HMAC for authentication.